# What's the last possible event I can catch after a user control has been shown in .net, winforms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, user-controls

as the title says, I'm looking for an event to catch after a user control has been shown.

At the moment, I have to set a do-once variable and catch the Invalidated event.

Answer (score 2):

What about [VisibleChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx)?

Comment: This does not help in the circumstance the question presents.  Visible changed is fired before the form shows.